# Ловля исключений в WCF службе

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, служба

Подскажите, как ловить Exception непосредственно на стороне службы?

Когда у меня вылетает исключение, то как место возникновения отображается канал на клиенте, а не в коде службы.

Как сделать, что бы ошибка отображалась в коде службы? Служба и клиент запускаются в режиме дебага.

Comment: А вы уверены, что именно сервис кидает ошибку?

Comment: Да. На стороне сервиса вылетает ошибка в LINQ запросе и тут же выполнение кода сервиса прерывается и меня кидает на канал с ошибкой :"Не задана ссылка на объект"

Comment: Банальный try/catch не подходит ? 
Ловить исключение и писать клиенту сообщение что что то не так.

Answer (score 2):

переписывайте OnError.

```
     protected override void OnError(DomainServiceErrorInfo errorInfo)
    {
        //сюда Ваша реакция
        base.OnError(errorInfo);


    }
```